# Flattening 'n' dimensional array

Tags: python

I have a 'n' dimensional array which I want to convert to 1'd

```
[[1', '2], '3', [4', '5', '6']]
```

to

```
[1', '2, '3', 4', '5' , '6']
```

I do not want to use numpy flatten function but want to achieve it through core python and efficient way. Apart from iterating them is there any inbuilt function to do it for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: The problem Im facing is example if I have  [[1', '2], '300', ['4', '5', '6']]., it becomes ['1', '2', '3', '0', '0', '4', '5', '6'] but I want [1', '2, '300', '4', '5', '6'] .. thats where the issue is

Comment: Try the solution from the question your question was marked a duplicate as, then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists